# How to compare within a group the first value to each subsequent value until a condition is met

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, iteration, rowwise

So I have a data frame in the general structure below:

dataframe:

| rownum | group | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2021-05-01 |
| 2 | a | 2021-05-02 |
| 3 | a | 2021-05-03 |
| 4 | b | 2021-05-15 |
| 5 | b | 2021-05-17 |
| 6 | b | 2021-05-30 |
| 7 | b | 2021-05-31 |
| 8 | b | 2021-05-31 |
| 9 | c | 2021-05-01 |
| 10 | c | 2021-05-05 |

What I would like to do is, WITHIN GROUP, compare the first row to the next row, until the difference between the dates meets some threshold, say 10 days. Then, once that row meets the threshold, I'd like to then test the next row against the subsequent row. It would look like this:

Result, using threshold of 10:

```
|rownum|group |date       |date diff|
|------|------|-----------|---|        
|1     | a    |2021-05-01 |NA|
|2     | a    |2021-05-02 |1|
|3     | a    |2021-05-03 |2|
|4     | b    |2021-05-15 |NA|
|5     | b    |2021-05-17 |2|
|6     | b    |2021-05-30 |15 (meets criteria, start from row 7 now)|
|7     | b    |2021-05-31 | NA|
|8     | b    |2021-05-31 | 0|
|9     | c    |2021-05-01 | NA|
|10    | c    |2021-05-05 |  4|
```

So to reiterate, its comparing the FIRST row of a group to subsequent rows until some threshold is met. Then the count starts over at the first rep after that within the group to subsequent rows within the group. The difference is recorded as datediff.

I've tried this but I dont know if sapply is the way to go:

```
dataframe %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(
        datediff = sapply(date, function(x) {
            all(difftime(dataframe$date,dplyr::lag(dataframe, n = 1, default = NA)))
                }
        )
    )
```

Also tried this, which I think is closer to what I want:

```
for (m in 1:length(dataframe)) {
    dataframe <- dataframe %>% 
        group_by(group) %>% 
        rowwise() %>% 
        mutate(datediff = difftime(dataframe$date,dplyr::lag(date, n = m, default = NA), units="days"))
    }
```

So far I havent been able to get the right rowwise comparison to even implement the thresholding bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `tidyverse` solution. We can use `accumulate` to achieve this task. `dat` is from r2evans' example.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(diff_lag = as.integer(date - lag(date))) %>%
  mutate(diff = accumulate(diff_lag, function(x, y){
    if (is.na(x)){
      res <- y
    }  else if (x > 10){
      res <- NA
    } else {
      res <- x + y
    }
    return(res)
  })) %>%
  select(-diff_lag) %>%
  ungroup()

dat2
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    rownum group date        diff
# <    int> <chr> <date>     <int>
#  1      1 a     2021-05-01    NA
#  2      2 a     2021-05-02     1
#  3      3 a     2021-05-03     2
#  4      4 b     2021-05-15    NA
#  5      5 b     2021-05-17     2
#  6      6 b     2021-05-30    15
#  7      7 b     2021-05-31    NA
#  8      8 b     2021-05-31     0
#  9      9 c     2021-05-01    NA
# 10     10 c     2021-05-05     4
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### base R

```r
func <- function(x, threshold = 10) {
  r <- rle(c(0, diff(x)) > threshold)
  if ((len <- length(r$values)) > 1) {
    r$lengths[len] <- r$lengths[len] - 1L
    r$lengths[1] <- r$lengths[1] + 1L
  }
  cumsum(inverse.rle(r))
}
dat$group2 <- ave(as.numeric(dat$date), dat$group, FUN = func)
dat$datediff <- ave(as.numeric(dat$date), dat[,c("group", "group2")], FUN = function(x) c(NA, (x - x[1])[-1]))
dat$group2 <- NULL
dat
#    rownum group       date datediff
# 1       1     a 2021-05-01       NA
# 2       2     a 2021-05-02        1
# 3       3     a 2021-05-03        2
# 4       4     b 2021-05-15       NA
# 5       5     b 2021-05-17        2
# 6       6     b 2021-05-30       15
# 7       7     b 2021-05-31       NA
# 8       8     b 2021-05-31        0
# 9       9     c 2021-05-01       NA
# 10     10     c 2021-05-05        4
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(group2 = func(date)) %>%
  group_by(group, group2) %>%
  mutate(datediff = c(NA, (date - date[1])[-1])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group2)
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    rownum group date       datediff
#     <int> <chr> <date>        <dbl>
#  1      1 a     2021-05-01       NA
#  2      2 a     2021-05-02        1
#  3      3 a     2021-05-03        2
#  4      4 b     2021-05-15       NA
#  5      5 b     2021-05-17        2
#  6      6 b     2021-05-30       15
#  7      7 b     2021-05-31       NA
#  8      8 b     2021-05-31        0
#  9      9 c     2021-05-01       NA
# 10     10 c     2021-05-05        4
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(rownum = 1:10, group = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c"), date = structure(c(18748, 18749, 18750, 18762, 18764, 18777, 18778, 18778, 18748, 18752), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

(I already converted `dat$date` to `Date`-class.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a roundabout way of getting what you're looking for, where some of your `NA` are set to `0` using this solution:

`library(tidyverse)`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         date_diff = date - first(date),
         flag = date_diff > 10) %>% 
  group_by(group, flag) %>% 
  mutate(temp_group = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  group_by(temp_group) %>% 
  mutate(date_diff = case_when(date_diff == first(date_diff) ~ date_diff,
                               date_diff != first(date_diff) & date_diff < 10 ~ date - first(date),
                               date_diff != first(date_diff) & date_diff > 10 ~ date - nth(date, 2))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(group, date, date_diff) 


# A tibble: 10 x 3
   group date       date_diff
   <chr> <date>     <drtn>   
 1 a     2021-05-01  0 days  
 2 a     2021-05-02  1 days  
 3 a     2021-05-03  2 days  
 4 b     2021-05-15  0 days  
 5 b     2021-05-17  2 days  
 6 b     2021-05-30 15 days  
 7 b     2021-05-31  0 days  
 8 b     2021-05-31  0 days  
 9 c     2021-05-01  0 days  
10 c     2021-05-05  4 days
```